# Probability - draw balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume there are 100 balls in the box, 50 are white and 50 are black. What is the probability that I draw 9 balls in which at most 4 are white (without replacement)? $(p(9 black)+p(1 white + 8 black) + P(2w + 7b)....+P(4w + 5b))$

I was thinking something like:
$$\frac{50}{100}.\frac{49}{99}.\frac{48}{98}.\frac{47}{97}$$
But it seems wrong because this assume only the first four draws are white, doesn't mean in total four are white....

Anyone help?

Comment: Your answer would be correct "asymptotically". Generally speaking, the hypergeometric distribution is relevant when trying to calculate probabilities without replacement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: You are correct: $\frac{50}{100}\cdot\frac{49}{99}\cdot\frac{48}{98}\cdot\frac{47}{97}$ describes exactly the chance that the first four balls are white. Now observe that there are $\binom{100}{4}$ ways to choose four balls from $100$ without replacement, and there are $\binom{50}{4}$ ways to choose four balls from the $50$ white ones without replacement. And $\binom{50}{4}/\binom{100}{4} = \ldots$? Your problem is just slightly more complicated, because you're selecting $w$ white balls and $b$ black balls while selecting $w+b=9$ balls altogether, and $w$ could be $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$.

Comment: $\frac{\binom{50}{4}}{\binom{100}{4}}$ = numbers of ways to choose 4 white balls from 100 correct ? So my answer should be $\frac{\binom{50}{4}}{\binom{100}{4}}+\frac{\binom{50}{3}}{\binom{100}{3}}+\frac{\binom{50}{2}}{\binom{100}{2}}+\frac{\binom{50}{1}}{\binom{100}{1}}+\frac{\binom{50}{0}}{\binom{100}{0}}$ ?

Comment: I mean ${\binom{50}{4}}/{\binom{100}{4}}+{\binom{50}{3}}/{\binom{100}{3}}+{\binom{50}{2}}/{\binom{100}{2}}+{\binom{50}{1}}/{\binom{100}{1}}+{\binom{50}{0}}/{\binom{100}{0}}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your logic is correct.   To find the individual probabilities, you can simply use combinatorics.

$$\begin{align}p(9\textsf{ black}) ~=~& \dfrac{\dbinom{50}{9}}{\dbinom{100}{9}}\\[2ex]p(1\textsf{ white}, 8\textsf{ black})~=~&\dfrac{\dbinom{50}{1}\cdot\dbinom{50}{8}}{\dbinom{100}{9}}\end{align}$$

... and so on.

---

PS: As a short cut, notice that $~p(\textsf{at least 4 black})~=~1-p(\textsf{less than 4 black})$

Comment: I think you meant to write $50\choose9$, etc., not $9\choose50$.

Comment: ya...that's what I confuse...thanks btw